# Codewars "Double Cola" Brainteaser

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving, recursive-algorithms

I encountered [this brainteaser](https://www.codewars.com/kata/double-cola/python) while coding, but it is essentially a math problem:

> Sheldon, Leonard, Penny, Rajesh and Howard are in the queue for a
>   "Double Cola" drink vending machine; there are no other people in the
>   queue. The first one in the queue (Sheldon) buys a can, drinks it and
>   doubles! The resulting two Sheldons go to the end of the queue. Then
>   the next in the queue (Leonard) buys a can, drinks it and gets to the
>   end of the queue as two Leonards, and so on.
>
> For example, Penny drinks the third can of cola and the queue will
>   look like this:
>
> `Rajesh, Howard, Sheldon, Sheldon, Leonard, Leonard, Penny, Penny`
>   Write a program that will return the name of a man who will drink the
>   n-th cola.
>
> Note that in the very beginning the queue looks like that:
>
> `Sheldon, Leonard, Penny, Rajesh, Howard`

After a long time I managed to come up with a long, contrived solution, although apparently the following works:

For a number $n$, subtract by 4 and then divide by 2, and then repeat as necessary until the number is at or below 5. Then you are done, with 1 = `Sheldon`, 2 = `Leonard`, etc.

Can anybody explain how exactly to derive this answer? It is very elegant although I have no clue what process would lead towards it.

Comment: Also, please feel free to edit to better tag this question.

Answer (score 5):

Let's call for simplicity the people a,b,c,d and e. Then it is not too hard to see they will come on the following order:

a, b, c, d, e

a,a, b,b, c,c, d,d, e,e (twice each)

a,a,a,a,  b,b,b,b, c,c,c,c, d,d,d,d, e,e,e,e (4 times each)

Then 8 times each, etc.

Informal proof:
Suppose each time a person gets a cola, he is created as a double person not in the end of line, but rather in a separate row. When the line is over, this row becomes the new line.
Then the (k+1)-th row is created by all people in the k-th row "doubling" themselves, at the same order.

Now, suppose you want to find the $n$-th person, and suppose $n$ is in the $k$-th row. When you subtract 4 from n and then divide by 2 you simply move to the same person in the $(k-1)$th row. You do that iteratively until you get to the first row.

Comment: @Looft: You made some grammar changes, fine, but why was the $4$ changed to $5$?

Comment: @BrianTung I solved a variant with open ranges, zero indexed. [0, 5) [5, 15)... The task is about mapping ranges to the original $[1, 5]$ range instead, I guess, the text is unavailable.

I see now that if row is using a closed range but starting from 1, first row $[1, 5]$, second $[6, 15]$, third $[16,35]$, fourth $[36,75]$.

Going to a neighboring row can only be done with -4 and division by 2.